# Need to reflect text in textView android

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, adt, mirror

I need to flip the text typed in textView in android. Example:

> Hello to olleH

I need to rotate all the text typed... someone told me to manually edit every string, but i 
can't do it as it is a textView and I do not know what the user types.

Here is my code (it is ActivityMain):

```
package com.LCPInt.reversealphabet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReverseMain extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reverse_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reverse_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void normal(View view){
    Log.e(TAG, "normale");
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1:
          setContentView(R.layout.normal);
          break;
    }
}
public void reverse(View view){
    Log.e(TAG, "reversed");
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.button2:
          setContentView(R.layout.reversed);
          break;
    }
    }
public void gen(View view){
    Log.e(TAG, "generate"); 
    Toast.makeText(this, "ciao", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: use reverse() from StringBuffer

Comment: @blackbelt can you please share a piece of code? i'm a bit a n00b! Thank

Comment: It's not clear whether you need to flip the text or the view itself. If you need to flip the view, you can use textView.getDrawingCache() to get a Bitmap object and then flip that and render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("Hello");
String reversed = stringBuffer.reverse().toString();
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse%28%29) the doc for reverse().

Edit:

```
String textViewText = textViewInstance.getText().toString();
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(textViewText);
String reversed = stringBuffer.reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Yes, but i need to flip the TEXTVIEW! not the String! :)

Comment: I just want to add that you can instantiate the StringBuffer with the text view's text with new StringBuffer(myTextView.getText().toString());

Comment: Thanks, but where do i have to put this string? In onClick? thank

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your end goal is, but you might be looking for the `android:textDirection` attribute which is used to provide correct text direction for right-to-left languages (e.g. Arabic).

See the [android:textDirection documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textDirection).

You can set this attribute on any view, not just a TextView.

The other answers will help you reverse the text that is typed into a TextView. This method will actually allow the user to enter the string in a right-to-left fashion. Depends what you are after!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
static String reverseMe(String s) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
     sb.append(s.charAt(i));
   return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: @user2606414 just call the function to get reversed string and set text to textview.

Comment: Can you please share something else? as i said i am a newbie

Comment: wherever you are setting the text to textview just do txtView.setText(  reverseMe("String you want to reverse")) and it will set text.

Comment: I don't want to reverse a string! i want to reverse the text typed in textview!

Comment: how can you type in textview?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
new StringBuilder("hello").reverse().toString()
```

Comment: Thank you, where to put this string? in onClick function? Thanks

Comment: @user2606414 you question is not so clear ! so please make some more sense !

Comment: Shared my code in first post... sorry for being late but i had to fight with stackoverflow!